# CPI vs. PointGuard

Tags: buffer-overflow

Has somebody compared CPI and PointGuard, which are two compiler-based tools for dealing with memory corruption?

Code Pointer Integrity (CPI): https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/osdi14/osdi14-paper-kuznetsov.pdf

PointGuard: https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/sec03/tech/full_papers/cowan/cowan.pdf

Although the two use very different techniques (CPI maintains metadata for each control-realted pointer and PointGuard encrypts pointers when they are stored in memory), both have to instrument the program code to change how pointers are used and both protect the values of pointers from being manipulated.

From what I can see, they share the same compatibility issue: if a library is not compiled using their custom compiler, the code in the library that uses protected pointers will trigger crash (CPI's debugging mode may not have that issue when the protected pointers are read, but the writing still has the same compatibility issue and the debugging mode is not secure for leaking information).

The CPI paper says that "PointGuard [13] ... face compatibility problems." This confused me as I think CPI does not have any advantage in terms of compatibility.

If you happen to have read the two papers, could you share some thoughts and compare their compatibility?